# What do named "tricks" share?

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, big-list, terminology

There are a number of theorems or lemmas or mathematical ideas that come to be known as eponymous
*tricks*, a term which in this context is in no sense derogatory.
Here is a list of 11 such tricks (the last of which I learned at MO):

- [the Whitney trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem#Eventual_consequences_of_the_Whitney_trick)
- [the DeTurck trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_DeTurck)
- [the Cayley trick](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0312069)
- [the Rabinowitsch trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabinowitsch_trick)
- [the Klee trick](https://books.google.com/books?id=Qo2DAwAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA66&dq=The+Klee+Trick&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=The%20Klee%20Trick&f=false)
- [the Moser trick](https://books.google.com/books?id=r9i6pXc7GEQC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=the+moser+trick&source=bl&ots=4nVYz9aKEm&sig=sG8G5goOxHGUj-M3l3VMPusnxho&hl=en&ei=trv5TO26HIW0lQeLuYDhBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=the%20moser%20trick&f=false)
- [the Herglotz trick](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-44205-0_25)
- [the Weyl trick](https://books.google.com/books?id=KmpCDg-D39gC&pg=PA218&lpg=PA218&dq=%22the+Weyl+Trick%22&source=bl&ots=NKP2YawGrh&sig=MSyWbbX-Vph0L62NWLLnhX7k_30&hl=en&ei=Qrz5TIDAN8GAlAfXq-GhBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20Weyl%20Trick%22&f=false)
- [the Karatsuba trick](https://doi.org/10.1109/ISDPE.2007.11)
- [the Jouanolou trick](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7374/the-jouanolou-trick)
- [Minty's trick](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249712/reference-on-mintys-trick)

**Edit: List augmented from the comments and answers:**

- [the Eilenberg–Mazur swindle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Mazur_swindle)
- the Parshin trick
- the Atiyah rotation trick
- the Higman trick
- [Rosser's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick)
- [Scott's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick)
- the Craig trick
- [the Uhlenbeck trick](https://books.google.com/books?id=T3gqWWbCd60C&pg=PA459&dq=the+Uhlenbeck+trick&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi95-Dl3L77AhV4SGwGHcQKB-kQ6AF6BAgBEAI#v=onepage&q=the%20Uhlenbeck%20trick&f=false)
- [the Alexander trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander%27s_trick)
- Grilliot's trick
- Zarhin's trick [For any abelian variety $A$, $(A \times A^{\vee})^4$ is principally polarizable.]
- [Kirby's torus trick](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263502/kirbys-torus-trick)
- [Trost's Discriminant trick](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36797/trosts-discriminant-trick)
- [The Brauer trick](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48248/what-do-named-tricks-share?noredirect=1#comment1043999_48248). Discussed in
  Gorenstein's [*Finite Simple Groups*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qqXqBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA98&dq=the+%22Brauer+trick%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjyg96c3b77AhW-RmwGHYuJCe4Q6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=the%20%22Brauer%20trick%22&f=false).

**Further Edit.** And although my original interest was in eponymous (=named-after-someone) tricks, several non-eponymous tricks have been mentioned, so I'll gather those here as well:

- the determinant trick
- [the kernel trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method#Mathematics:_the_kernel_trick)
- [the W-trick](https://web.archive.org/web/20210412031856/https://asone.ai/polymath/index.php?title=W-trick)

Some of those listed above do not yet have Wikipedia pages (hint, hint—Thierry).

I (JOR) am not seeking to extend this list (although I would be incidentally interested to learn of
prominent omissions), but rather I am wondering:

> Is there some aspect or trait shared by the mathematical ideas or techniques that,
> over time, come to be *named* "tricks"?

Comment: "An idea which can be used only once is a trick. If one can use it more than once it becomes a method."  Quoted from http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=b9l2NqGEFzgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Problems++and+Theorems++in+Analysis+I&hl=en&ei=Ssf5TIzTF8m24Abwq63_Bg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: That construction of Whitney ought to have a more dignified name.

Comment: You could add the Eilenberg Swindle to your list.  (A Swindle sounds even more disreputable than a Trick.)

Comment: Why is the page linking to the Whitney trick linking to a "Global Oneness" site? 
<br>
<br>
Why do they even have a page on Whitney embedding on a site about spirituality? I'm very confused.

Comment: Are you expecting a definitive answer to this? If not, then CW would surely be in order?

Comment: @Simon: I replaced the strange Whitney trick link.  Sorry about that.

Comment: How about "Atiyah's Rotation Trick"?  It is most famous for its role in proving Bott periodicity, but it comes up elsewhere in operator theory as well.  Yet it still deserves to be called a trick, in my opinion.

Comment: @Joseph: I'm more wondering why they had that on their site than otherwise.

Comment: @Simon: Yes, it does make one wonder! I suspect the web site is constructed by _wisdom-seeking bots_, and it is somehow appropriate that they stumble upon the profound Whitney trick :-). For those mystified because I replaced the link, here is the original: http://www.experiencefestival.com/whitney_embedding_theorem_-_whitney_trick

Comment: There's also the Higman Trick (for manipulating invertible matrices over polynomial rings and such -- probably akin to the Atiyah rotation trick).

Comment: There's the "Craig trick" showing that theories with r.e. axiomatizations have recursive axiomatizations.

Comment: There's the Alexander trick, showing that two homeomorphisms of the ball which agree on the boundary are isotopic. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_trick

Comment: It seems appropriate to link to the Tricki here in the comments http://www.tricki.org/

Comment: You're also missing the "Uhlenbeck trick" which is central in Ricci flow just as the deTurck trick.

I think that the tendency to call them 'tricks' versus 'methods' is really a matter of personal taste and/or what people are used to from mathematicians that they learned from. I personally don't like using 'trick' for anything in mathematics.

Comment: I believe that there’s more than one “Scott’s trick”, though unfortunately I can’t recall what the others are!  But I definitely remember mentioning the cardinality (or more generally, quotients-of-classes) trick in a seminar once, and being told by several audience members that “Scott’s trick” meant something else to them.  Of course, that was in Pittsburgh (though some years after Scott moved away), so the audience were probably particularly familiar with his tricks.

Comment: Missing from your list at the moment is the "determinant trick" in commutative algebra.

Comment: ... and the "kernel trick" is also not named for a person, but it is called "trick"

Comment: There is also "Grilliot's trick" in computability theory. 

Comment: Another one is the W-trick: http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=W-trick
With it, you intersect the primes with a suitably chosen arithmetic progression to increase their density and make them look more random.

Comment: A new question is emerging: Why are some tricks named after their inventor, but other (determinant-, kernel-, W-) tricks not?

Comment: Just to add to your list -- one of the commenters above has a trick named after him :-) Nikolov and Pyber used a result of Gowers about solving equations in groups to prove a nice fact about the multiplication of (large) sets in groups. The method they used is known as **the Gowers trick**. I believe it was Pyber who came up with the name -- you can see the name in use in the literature in several places, for instance in Breuillard's *Introduction to approximate groups*.

Comment: Another possible entry in the list : **the Frattini argument**. I thought of it when I read Qiaochu's answer (which I thought was spot on) -- it's a very handy little, um, **thingy** to know when working with finite groups.

Comment: There's the Moser trick in symplectic geometry. But actually people abuse the use of this name by "applying" it whenever there's a flow transporting some isomorphism.

Comment: There's the "Brauer trick" in finite group theory for proving that two subgroups of a finite group generate a proper subgroup. It has worked more than once, but it has a magical feeling. Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of the finite group $G$. Let $\chi$ be a non-principal irreducible complex character of $G$. If $(\chi_H,1_H)+(\chi_K,1_K)>(\chi_{H\cap K},1_{H\cap K})$, then $\langle H,K \rangle<G$.

Comment: The link for the Karatsuba trick is probably supposed to go to the paper [On Karatsuba Multiplication Algorithm](https://doi.org/10.1109/ISDPE.2007.11). (Although I wasn't sure - and it is possible that the current link doesn't work only for me.)
It's quite difficult to say what the links for the Herglotz trick used to be. (Of course, the link rot [for the springerlink.com links](https://mathoverflow.net/search?tab=active&q=url%3a%22%2Aspringerlink.com%2A%22) is a well-known issue.)

Comment: what about the **17 camels trick**s ( https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271608/17-camels-trick)?

Comment: Is there a trick for counting 11 tricks as 10?

Comment: I was an author on a paper called Hamiltonian Swindles. A reviewer complained. I was able to reply with a quote from a paper summarizing what might be called a swindle in the relevant domain. And that allowed me to keep the name. So never let it be said that these kinds of questions aren't relevant to anything :)

Answer (score 61):

How about the following (which I think applies to some of these tricks but not others): a trick is something whose usefulness is not fully captured by any particular set of hypotheses, so it would limit its usefulness to write it down as a lemma.

Comment: This is my favorite answer.  It captures the notion that a trick is one of the essentially human contributions to math, a creative touch that isn't part of some axiomatic or algorithmic approach that something more mechanical might invent.  It's generalizable but not categorizable.

Comment: I like this answer, but I'm not sure it really distinguishes between tricks and methods. For instance, I don't know of a lemma one could write down that would do justice to the probabilistic method in combinatorics. But actually I'm tempted to say that "Take a random X" feels like a trick that can be applied over and over again, perhaps for this very reason.

Comment: @Ryan: I must also leap to the defence of the poor old computer. I don't see any reason in principle that a clever program could not invent mathematical tricks. (I think a proof that a program couldn't invent tricks would prove that humans couldn't either.)

Answer (score 42):

One well-known trick is a way to evaluate the Gaussian integral $G = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-x^2}dx = \sqrt{\pi}$ by writing
$$G^2 = \left(\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-x^2}dx\right)\left(\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-y^2}dy\right)
= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$$
which when transformed to polar coordinates becomes
$$G^2 = 2\pi \int_0^\infty e^{-r^2} r dr = \pi \int_0^\infty e^{-u} du = \pi$$
via the substitution $u=r^2$.  It appears this idea is due to Poisson.

In a 2005 note in the American Mathematical MONTHLY, R. Dawson has observed that this is a trick that only works once; there are no other integrals that can be evaluated by this method.  Specifically:

**Theorem.** Any Riemann-integrable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, such that $f(x)f(y) = g(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ for some $g$, is of the form $f(x)=ke^{ax^2}$.

See: *Dawson, Robert J. Mac G.*, [**On a “singular” integration technique of Poisson**](https://dx.doi.org/10.2307/30037446), Am. Math. Mon. 112, No. 3, 270-272 (2005). [ZBL1088.26500](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1088.26500).

So if a technique is a trick that works twice, this one is definitely still a trick.

Comment: Note that this trick has something in common with the Rabinowitsch, Cayley and Eilenberg tricks and probably some others on the list: in order to solve a $k$-dimensional problem, you go into more than $k$ dimensions. This also seems to be a distinguishing feature of things called tricks.

Comment: I think Dawson was anticipated by James Clerk Maxwell.  A result called Maxwell's theorem says that if $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are independent real-valued random variables and their joint density is spherically symmetric, then all of them are normally distributed, i.e. the probability density of each of them is a Gaussian function.

Comment: Constantine Georgakis, "A Note on the Gaussian Integral", _Mathematics Magazine_, February, 1994, page 47

This paper gives what its author considers "a better alternative to the usual method of reduction to polar coordinates" for evaluating this integral.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral .

Comment: While the specific form $f(x) f(y) = g(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ applies only to Gaussians, there *are* further uses of this kind of transformation: in one direction, to the volumes of Euclidean spheres in higher dimension (imagine you already know $\Gamma(1/2)$ but not the area of a circle); in another direction, to the usual proof of $B(x,y) = \Gamma(x) \Gamma(y) / \Gamma(x+y)$; combining these, to Dirichlet integrals; and by analogue, to the relation between Gauss sums and Jacobi sums — and probably others that don't come to mind right now.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: that "better alternative" in the paper by Georgakis in fact is due to Laplace. See http://www.york.ac.uk/depts/maths/histstat/normal_history.pdf.

Comment: For a different version of this trick, in which we use a Cartesian-to-Cartesian transformation, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4231128/248217).

Comment: References, clickably: [Dawson - On a "singular" integration trick of Possion](https://doi.org/10.2307/30037446); [Georgakis - A note on the Gaussian integral](https://doi.org/10.2307/2690556) ([mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48248/what-do-named-tricks-share/263508#comment117411_48397) by @MichaelHardy).

Answer (score 40):

I'll take a stab at this.

I think that the term "trick" is used to connote a technique that achieves something as if by magic. If I make a cake by combining flour, sugar, and eggs and baking, that is simply a standard technique, but if I make the cake by putting the ingredients into a top hat and waving a wand over it, that is a magic trick. The way that the Weyl unitary trick makes complex groups behave like compact ones seems like a magic trick. (For those of you trying to follow this half baked analogy, the cake is complete reducibility of representations, the oven is integration, and the hat is ... uhhh....  )

Comment: Ha ha, half baked :)

Comment: I think this is the answer.

Comment: The hat is orthogonality?

Comment: The hat is Fourier transform, of course!

Answer (score 38):

To my way of thinking, the other answers are missing an important
element, a necessary feature for a mathematical tool or method to
be called "trick."

Namely, in order to be called a "trick," a method or technique
must involve artifice or misdirection of some kind. When we treat a mathematical
object as something that it isn't really or when we pretend that
something is other than it is in order to advance an argument (which is not to suggest that the mathematics is not correct), then we
are using trickery. When we solve a problem by placing our focus on something else, in which we aren't actually interested as such and which may even be silly in some way—a kind of misdirection—but by doing so we become successful in the original problem, then we are using trickery. When we replace a robust concept, in which we are really interested, with a modified version of it, perhaps even an absurd version of it, but which makes the argument work, then we are using trickery.

For example, with Craig's trick, we replace a formula $\varphi$ with
the conjunction with itself
$\varphi\wedge\varphi\wedge\dots\wedge\varphi$ repeated many times
over. The new assertion is just silly and we don't actually care about it as such, although of course it is logically equivalent to $\varphi$. How could it possibly help? The point is that we can use the new assertion to code some extra information into an axiomatization or presentation: the number of times it was repeated. By this artifice, we can deduce that every computably enumerable theory
has a computable set of axioms. The same idea works in many other contexts. For example, every c.e. presentable group has a computable presentation, by sufficiently repeating relations suitably in the presentation.

With Scott's trick, the issue to be solved is that the equivalence
class of an object forms a proper class, which can cause certain
problems, and so we replace that equivalence class with the *set*
of rank-minimal members of the class. If we think of this fake
equivalence class as the real thing, then everything works great!
This trick is surprisingly robust, and can be used to find small
canonical sets of representing structures in almost any situation.
For example, in ZFC there is a definable manner of choosing a
*set* of groups from each group isomorphism class: the
rank-minimal groups from that class. This is a trick, because we
don't really care much about that particular collection as such.

With Rosser's trick, we replace the concept of a theory $T$
proving a sentence $\sigma$, with: $T$ proves $\sigma$ by a proof
for which there is no shorter proof of $\neg\sigma$. When you
think of "proof" using this concept, then Gödel's
incompleteness theorem is improved to the Gödel-Rosser
theorem, where one can drop Gödel's extra hypotheses about
$\omega$-consistency. This is a trick, because we don't actually
want to think about "proof" using Rosser's concept, except that
it makes the argument work.

In many of the other tricks, we do something that seems a little absurd at first, misdirecting our attention from the original problem to this other thing, which may seem irrelevant at first, but when we follow it more fully it provides the answer we seek.

In each case, we replace the concepts or objects in which we are
truly interested by concepts or objects that we don't actually
care about as such and which in several cases are comical versions of the original, except that they make the argument work.

Comment: In particular, I don't agree with the "used only once" joke idea for distinguishing tricks and methods. We have already many counterexamples to that view mentioned on this thread of posts. Some of these tricks are robust mathematical methods; but they are still tricks, because they involve artifice.

Comment: How do you view unanticipatability as criterion? Also, is the following a "trick" in your view? $$ \int \sec x\,dx = \int \frac{(\sec x)(\sec x+\tan x)}{\sec x+\tan x} \, dx = \int\frac{du} u $$

Comment: Michael, I think that is a good part of the criterion. And yes, I would count that as a trick, since one wouldn't be interested in that quotient, except for the fact that it enables the method, and so this is the kind of misdirection I was writing about.

Comment: I like the emphasis on misdirection, that is indeed a key ingredient of magic tricks. However, in geometric tricks (e.g. Whitney), I have the impression that 'wonder' is the essence: the author considers a spectacularly crafted object that makes the solution evident.

Answer (score 13):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick

"A technique is a trick that works twice"

Note that Grothendieck never published his proof of the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem because he felt that the proof depended on an "astuce" (trick) rather than flowing naturally.

Comment: It is interesting that the accepted English translation of "astuce" is "trick", whereas that of the adjectival form "astucieux/euse" is "clever" or "astute".  This seems to give the concept of a trick a better connotation in French than in English.  (I am tempted to load up *Lord of the Rings* with the French subtitles on to see whether Gollum accuses Frodo and Sam of being "astucieux".)  

Comment: @Pete: you're absolutely right. For instance, to translate the expression "dirty trick" into French, you would not use the word "astuce" because "astuce" has a uniformly positive connotation of praise (yes, even in that Gollum context).  

Comment: In French, one says "un artifice de calcul", "l'artifice de Legendre". By the way, there is also the van der Waerden trick (associativity of the composition of reduced words).

Answer (score 6):

[Scott's Trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick) is called a "trick" because it is not actually necessary for the completion of the proof in which it is involved; however, without the trick the proof is massively more tedious.  Although the other tricks may not have a widely-agreed-upon-reason for being a trick, I suspect that they may be called such for similar reasons.

Comment: Same for the Rabinowitsch trick. Also as pointed in another answer, the Rabinowitsch trick works only once (although similar ideas must be used, albeit in less famous circumstances).

Comment: Well, it’s only unnecessary if you’re assuming AC (which was not, if I understand right, quite as entrenchedly automatic among set theorists back in the ’60s as it is now).  It’s necessary if you want to talk about cardinalities — and more generally, construct quotients of classes by equivalence relations — in ZF and many other set theories.

Answer (score 6):

There's always Feynman's trick. It's more common amongst physicists; Feynman, afterall was a physicist. Although quite standard now, back in Feynman's hayday he was able to solve many complicated integrals by adding another variable, using an auxiliary function, solving a basic integral involving the auxiliary function, and then differentiating said variable to get the correct integral. This is common now, but when Feynman would use it, people wouldn't understand how he'd solved such complicated integrals so fast. It's very diverse too, in that it applies in many scenarios. One example I always found interesting, off the top of my head, was using it to prove that the Gamma function interpolates the factorial in one line:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{n}\,dx = (-1)^{n}\frac{d^{n}}{dt^{n}}\Big{|}_{t=1}\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}\,dx = \frac{d^{n}}{dt^{n}}\Big{|}_{t=1} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{t} = n!$$

though is of no way limited to this single, obvious, instance. One can solve the $\text{sinc}$ integral using this. One can simplify the amount of work one needs by using this little trick.

It is a trick in the sense that it's very simple. It's a little magic, where persons usually go "where'd you think of using that extra variable and that second function and taking the derivative?" It's basic and easy to understand, isn't a theorem or a lemma really (putting down hypotheses or conditions blurs its simplicity). It's just a technique one tries when solving integrals; like partial fractions or trigonometric substitution; except it takes a while to get a hang of using, and at first seems extraneous. I think that's an important fact to something being a trick: it isn't obvious, but it's easy, and it takes a while to get in the hang of using it. As a kicker, Feynman's trick can go very far with little work; Feynman made a living off using this trick.

Comment: I wouldn't attribute this "trick" (method?) to Feynman, although he helped to raise awareness of it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Examples

Comment: @ToddTrimble I know it isn't technically Feynman's (maybe I should've made that clearer), but people have gotten into the swing of calling it Feynman's trick (or Feynman's method; it goes by both names), especially physicists. That's its nomer, and Feynman used it notoriously. I like to call it a trick, because it's really simple and reminds me of a card trick, there's some sleight of hand involved; and that's how it was first called when I heard of it. I also think it's a bit more involved than just Leibniz's integral rule.

Comment: This is essentially the "differentiation under the integral sign" trick. I like  its application to $\int_0^\infty \sin xdx/x$ best.

Comment: @FanZheng It is essentially this. But by adding the "Feynman" it makes a closer semantic connection to: how effective it is, how it can be used in complicated ways, and that it's even applicable in very advanced scenarios. Especially when you see how Feynman uses it.

Comment: Another example on introducing an extra variable-the integral of the bell function over $\ \mathbb R\ $ was (is?) popular on American tests and exams. One computes its square as a product of two such integrals but each w.r. to a different variable. Then a student treats it as one integral over $\ \mathbb R^2 $ Then switch to the polar coordinates.

Comment: Ooops, before my comment above, the bell function has appeared in @Nate Eldredge's answer.

Comment: By the way, this "trick" has been promoted to a "method" by Gert Almkvist and Doron Zeilberger: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717108801599 Let me also mention this article, that ties this trick to "creative telescoping" and the Wilf-Zeilberger method: https://specfun.inria.fr/chyzak/Publications/Chyzak-2012-CTP.pdf

Comment: Titles of @ToddTrimble's [references](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48248/what-do-named-tricks-share#comment650844_263508):  [Almkvist and Zeilberger - The method of differentiating under the integral sign](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0747-7171(08)80159-9) and [Chyzak - Creative Telescoping for Parametrised Integration and Summation](https://doi.org/10.5802/ccirm.14).

Comment: Thank you, @LSpice!

Comment: Yes, this is how physicists usually like to call “connecting the integral to a know one by adding a parameter, and study the dependence from it”, which is something that mathematicians do on a daily base since Newton and Euler. Usually, in the computation, what is the key point for many of them (writing a formula) is the trivial part for a mathematician, and  what is the key point for a mathematician (e.g. justifying the passage to the limit)  is simply ignored by them as non-physical  :P

Answer (score 5):

While tricks have names because they wind up being associated with with some particular mathematician, tricks are tricks because something important goes on "behind the curtain."

For instance, to prove
$$
(a_1 b_1 + \cdots + a_n b_n)^2 \leq  ({a_1}^2 +  \cdots + {a_n}^2) ({b_1}^2 +  \cdots + {b_n}^2),
$$
write
\begin{align*}
A &= ({a_1}^2 +  \cdots + {a_n}^2)\\\
B &= (a_1 b_1 + \cdots + a_n b_n)\\\
C &= ({b_1}^2 +  \cdots + {b_n}^2),
\end{align*}
then we must show
$$
B^2 \leq AC.
$$
Equality clearly holds when $A = 0$. Otherwise, since $\mathbb{R}$ has no negative squares, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
0 \leq (a_1 x - b_1)^2 + \cdots + (a_n x - b_n)^2.
$$
Expanding the squares,
$$
0 \leq Ax^2 - 2Bx + C.
$$

> The quadratic expression vanishes
>   whenever $$ x = \frac{B}{A} \pm
> > \sqrt{\left(\frac{B}{A}\right)^2 -
> > \frac{C}{A}}. $$

If $x = \dfrac{B}{A}$, then
$$
0 \leq A\left(\frac{B}{A}\right)^2 - 2 B\left(\frac{B}{A}\right) + C =  \frac{B^2}{A} - 2 \frac{B^2}{A} + C = - \frac{B^2}{A} + C,
$$
thus
$$
B^2 \leq AC.
$$

Answer (score 4):

I've long known the adage that a "trick" works only once whereas a "method" works in multiple instances, or maybe is expected to work in yet unanticipated future instances.

But there's another POV: a trick is something whose efficacy cannot be anticipated, but only by hindsight is seen to work.  All methods I've seen of finding $\int \sec x \ dx$ are "tricks".  I've always leaned toward viewing unanticipatability as the essence of trickhood.

But I also like Qiaochu Yuan's answer.

Comment: There is an algorithm to find the integral of any rational function of trigonometric functions: use a rational parameterization (e.g. using tan x/2), then use partial fractions (or a residue computation, etc.).  I don't see how this is a "trick" in any sense.  It is a direct corollary of the fact that the circle is birational to the projective line.

Comment: There's the argument often used in calculus texts:
`$$
\sec x = \frac{\sec x(\tan x + \sec x)}{\sec x + \tan x} = \frac{\sec x \tan x + \sec^2 x}{\sec x + \tan x} = \frac{du}{u}
$$`
where $u$ is the last denominator above.  That seems like a "trick".  I've seen other methods but I don't remember what they are right now.  One of them seemed to take some of the mystery out of it, but it was still a trick.

But I can't show a residue computation to a first-year calculus class.

The "Weierstrass trick" (was it Weierstrass?) of $\tan(x/2)$, etc., does seem a bit more like a "method".

Comment: Yes, I agree that that argument is trick-like.  The rational parameterization of the circle is not.  It is a natural and beautiful geometric argument (just taking the slope of a line between two points) and I think it could easily be presented to a first-year calculus class.  

Comment: The tan(x/2) formulas can be derived from basic trigonometric identities, and that's the way I learned them in high-school. Needless to say, when I realized the link with the rational parametrization, I was extatic. 

Comment: Dammit, I'm being clumsy, and I can't edit a comment here after I've posted it.  To atone for my sin, I'll try to get it right:
$$
\sec x\ dx = \frac{\sec x(\tan x + \sec x)}{\sec x + \tan x}\ dx = \frac{\sec x \tan x + \sec^2 x}{\sec x + \tan x}\ dx = \frac{du}{u}.
$$

Comment: @Michael Hardy: I asked this question about ways of evaluating $\int \sec x dx$ on math.SE about two months ago.  You might be interested in the answers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6695

Comment: @Thierry: Anyone who likes the tangent-half-angle formula might like this version of it that has some symmetry not found in the versions always seen in present-day texts:
$$
\tan\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2} = \frac{\sin\alpha + \sin\beta}{\cos \alpha + \cos\beta}.
$$
Could that be useful for anything related to integrals like these?

Comment: I had a student come up with a different way to do this, on the fly, on the final exam.  Write 
$$
\sec(x) = {1\over \sqrt{1 - \sin^2(x)}}, 
$$
then substitute $u = \sin(x)$ and use partial fractions!

Comment: I usually integrate this function differently (using something trick-like, but natural one):
$$\frac{dx}{\cos(x)} = \frac{\cos(x)dx}{{\cos^2(x)}} = 
\frac{d(\sin(x)}{1 - {\sin^2(x)}}$$

Comment: A fairly new Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_the_secant_function

Raise your hand if you knew that this was a famous conjecture in the 17th century.  Or that it was originally done for the purposes of cartography (I think maybe lots of people know that).  Or that Isaac Newton was aware of the conjecture and wrote about it, and Isaac Barrow was the first to prove it.

Answer (score 4):

Would regarding a scalar as the trace of a $1\times1$ matrix be considered a "trick"?

Here's an occasion where that's useful:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_of_covariance_matrices#Maximum-likelihood_estimation_for_the_multivariate_normal_distribution

Answer (score 3):

Looooong before I was old (then I was ancient, and now I am archeological), this is what I said:

*The difference between a method and a trick is **understanding**.*

That's all.

> **Trick => method (evolution)**:   Observe, that once a "trick" is understood it becomes a *method*. Often, it is still called a *trick* for various reasons like tradition, recreational value, inertia, etc.
>
> And just a distant association (poetry): once a kenning becomes common, it gets simplified to a metaphor--the metaphor is then like a hint (of that kenning). Perhaps this is one of the reasons why literary critics often are confused, they say that kenning is a kind of a metaphor (hmmm....). Thus we get another evolution: 1.trick => method, 2.kenning => metaphor. (Didn't I say ***distant***?)

Comment: I really disagree with this - I think there are lots of things called "tricks" which we completely understand. E.g. I don't think there's really anything left to understand about Craig's trick.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, there are vague intentions of what people expect from a word. Those expectations are not consistent. That's how natural languages are. And then people ask about the so-called "real meaning" of a word. But there is no such thing. Thus, the best, if we care, we should hopefully agree on the definition of the term which is the most useful. This in particular means simplicity(!). Other considerations are avoiding a new synonym, etc. Of course, one needs to sacrifice some examples. *** There is need of definitions of terms also outside mathematics, e.g. in poetry.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, even in pure mathematics, we do have definitions but we hardly ever have anything like "real meaning". Even great mathematicians were fooling themselves when they expected, say, "true real numbers"--again, there was never anything like "true real numbers". Thus, the definitions should be profound and useful but shouldn't attempt "real meaning". Ironically,  the same definition (but for trivial linguistic variations) may be meaningful to different chapters of mathematics, e.g. probability and mechanics. Then how can it have one true meaning (in the usual sense)? Funny.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński That's a very functional linguistics thing to say on a math forum. It's nice to see mathematicians engage in a healthy dialogue of the ideal semantics of a word; the blurred line between signifiers and the signified. After reading your comment; it framed your answer much more clearly. +1

Comment: And your edit made it even more poignant!

Comment: @james.nixon, thank you (on this sooo-harsh board, you're spoiling me :-) ).

Comment: As I mentioned under James Nixon's answer, I think that in promoting the trick of differentiating under the integral sign to a method, Gert Almkvist and Doron Zeilberger understand something like what is said in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

A trick is a mathematical [life hack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_hack).

A life hack is a simple but unexpected solution to a somewhat frequently occurring problem. So it is with a trick; it provides a simple and unexpected solution to a problem that seems baffling to those who don't know the trick. It is important that the trick be *unexpected* to the uninitiated; if a problem is manifestly a "standard" problem that we expect to have a "standard" solution that we can look up in a "standard" reference, then the standard solution will not be considered a trick. It is also important that the trick have an "easy when you know how" feel to it; if the method is too laborious then we are unlikely to call it a trick.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to mention an important trick in Vanishing theorem in algebraic geometry-The "cyclic cover trick", which is in the MO question: [what is the cyclic cover trick?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134145/what-is-the-cyclic-cover-trick)

Answer (score 1):

Your question reminds me of Prof. Tao's description of the **tensor power trick**.
Although sounding as an indirect answer, it might be useful to show the POV of a an exceptional mathematician (and profound thinker) about a topic he masterly treated.
Verbatim from [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/09/05/amplification-arbitrage-and-the-tensor-power-trick/): *The amplification trick is a deceptively simple one, but it can become particularly powerful when one is arbitraging an unintuitive symmetry, such as symmetry under tensor powers. Indeed, the “tensor power trick”, which can eliminate constants and even logarithms in an almost magical manner, can lead to some interesting proofs of sharp inequalities, which are difficult to establish by more direct means.*

Comment: I don't think Tao ever claimed that this was "his" trick. It wouldn't surprise me if some version of this was being used by Hardy and Littlewood, or Dirichlet, or Legendre, or Euler, or ...

Comment: You are absolutely right, @Yemon; the origin of this trick is not from Terence Tao. Prof. Tao treated it and, above all, explained it in such an original way I thought it deserved a quotation in this answer. In my opinion, another interesting verbatim fom the same source is: "more generally, the tensor power trick can convert restricted or weak-type estimates into strong-type estimates."

Comment: Let me also quote from the original question: "I (JOR) am not seeking to extend this list (although I would be incidentally interested to learn of prominent omissions), but rather I am wondering: Is there some aspect or trait shared by the mathematical ideas or techniques that, over time, come to be named "tricks"?". I don't see how your answer addresses this question.

Comment: Yes @YemonChoi , my contribution was an indirect answer, a way of replying that could raise some bafflement.
Anyway, I don’t think (or at least I hope) to have gone totally astray.
In my eyes, the inspiring words of Prof. Tao teach us that “tricks” are deceptively simple and particularly powerful (almost magical), leading to some interesting proofs which are difficult to establish by more direct means. This is the reason why I wished to share that stimulating quotation.

Answer (score 0):

A nice trick by Edmund Landau:

Let us suppose that we need to show the validity of Bertrand's postulate for every $n<4000$ (as in [Erdős's famous 1932 paper](https://www.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/Erdos.html)).  According to Erdős, in the case under consideration, Landau's teachings imply that one does not have to look for a prime number in all of the intervals

$$(1,2], (2,4], (3,6], (4,8], \ldots, (3999, 7998],$$

and that it suffices to ponder the following list of fourteen primes in which each of them is smaller than twice the other:

$$2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 23, 43, 83, 163, 317, 631, 1259, 2503, 4001.$$

Indeed, if $N \in [2,4000) \cap \mathbb{N}$, let us denote by $p_{N}$ the greatest prime in the list that is smaller than or equal to $N$; then, if $p_{N+1}$ is the prime in the list that comes right after $p_{N}$, it holds that $p_{N+1} \in (N,2N]$ and we are done.

If a trick is an idea which can be used only once, then the previous "Bemerkung" by Landau (as Erdős refers to it in the aforementioned paper) is definitely deserving of being declared as one, right?

Answer (score 0):

A **"trick"** is something that can be clearly seen by hindsight to succeed, but could not be anticipated.

For example:
$$
\int \sec x\, dx = \int \frac{(\sec x)(\sec x + \tan x)}{\sec x + \tan x} \, dx = \int \frac{du}u
$$

Comment: You appear to agree with thirteen years younger version of yourself: https://mathoverflow.net/a/48286/345.