# Reference on Minty's trick

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, limits-and-convergence

I am searching for a precise reference for the following result:

> Consider $f:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+$ a nondecreasing function.
>
> Assume that a sequence of nonnegative functions $(u_n)_n$ converges
> weakly in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ to some element $u$. Assume also that
> $(f(u_n))_n$ belongs to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and converges weakly in this
> space to some element $v$.
>
> Then, if $(u_n f(u_n))_n$ converges weakly (in the sense of positive
> measures say) to $uv$, one has $v=f(u)$ a.e.
>
> If furthemore $f$ is strictly increasing, then $(u_n)_n$ converges
> a.e.

The previous result(s) belong somehow to the folklore of nonlinear PDE and are known with different namings (Minty's trick, Leray-Lions' trick *etc*).

I am searching for a precise (if possible modern) reference including the strictly increasing case.

Answer (score 2):

I think a standard referenz is "Quelques méthodes de résolution des problèmes aux limites non linéaires" from Lions, but it is in french.

Comment: The OP is looking for "a precise reference", and you only "think"?

Comment: The person is attempting to help.  If you want to discourage their participation, I think you are doing the right thing. If you want to help, you could verify or expand upon (or refute) their thought.  Gerhard "At Least It's A Lead" Paseman, 2018.07.06.

Answer (score 2):

The original reference is:

Minty, George J., 
on a "monotonicity'' method for the solution of non-linear equations in Banach spaces. 
Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. U.S.A. 50 1963 1038–1041. 47.80, https://www.pnas.org/content/50/6/1038

and a "modern" reference, from which your version follows very easily is Lemma D.10 in

[The Gradient Discretisation Method : A framework for the discretisation of linear and nonlinear elliptic and parabolic problems](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01382358). J. Droniou, R. Eymard, T. Gallouët, C. Guichard, R. Herbin. 
Springer International Publishing AG, série Mathématiques et Applications, (501 pages) - 2018
(online version is "official", and it's in English :)